# How to de-index pages from google using robots.txt

Tags: seo

I added the no-index tag for the google-bot, but it is kind of taking a long time to de-index some pages since I have over 100k pages I need to de-index lol :)))

What is the proper way to de-index pages using robots.txt?

Thanks!

Any idea how long should it take?

Comment: I will recomended you remove page from Google webmaster tool.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming these pages still exist, but you just want them removed from search results...

> What is the proper way to de-index pages using robots.txt?

You wouldn't necessarily use `robots.txt` to *de-index* pages. ie. remove already indexed pages from the Google search results. A `noindex` robots meta tag in the page itself (or `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP response header) might be preferable instead, in combination with the [URL removal tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846?hl=en) in Google Search Console (GSC) to speed up the process.

`robots.txt` specifically blocks *crawling* (not necessarily "indexing"). By blocking these pages from being *crawled*, these pages should naturally drop from the search index in time, but this can take a considerable amount of time. However, if these pages are still being linked to then they may not disappear entirely from the search results if these URLs are blocked by `robots.txt` (you can end up with a URL-only link in the SERPS, with no description).

Using `robots.txt` to remove the `https://www.example.com/getridofthis/` directory...

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /getridofthis/
```

To remove pages entirely from SERPs consider using a `noindex` meta tag (or `X-Robots-tag: noindex` HTTP response header) instead of `robots.txt`. (Which is what it sounds like you are doing already.) Don't block crawling in `robots.txt` as this will prevent the crawler from seeing the `noindex` meta tag.

To expedite the process of de-indexing URLs in Google search you can use the [URL removal tool in GSC](https://search.google.com/search-console/removals) (formerly Webmaster Tools). For this tool to be effective long-term you need to use the `noindex` meta tag in the pages themselves. (The [original blog article](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/03/url-removal-explained-part-i-urls.html) stated that `robots.txt` could be used as a blocking mechanism with the URL removal tool, however, [recent help documents](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846?hl=en#make_permanent) specifically warn against using `robots.txt` for "permanent removal".)

Reference:

- Google Removals Tool
  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846?hl=en

Comment: robots.txt prevents google from crawling and seeing noindex, so blocking both indexing and crawling with noindex and robots.txt is equivalent to only blocking crawling using robots.txt

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Very true. I've updated my answer to clarify that. Thanks. (In fact, I ended up reworking my answer. Some of the points in the original blog article I linked to with regards to `robots.txt` and the URL removal tool are no longer recommended in the more recent help documents.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/) has all the info you need.